# Singularity definition file with paths relative to it

Tags: singularity-container

#### Question

When building Singularity images using definition files, is there a way to specify the path to a file on the host system relative to the definition file (i.e. independent of where the build command is called)?

#### Example to Illustrate the Problem

I have the following files in the same directory (e.g. a git repository):

- foobar.def
- some_file.txt

`foobar.def` looks as follows:

```
Bootstrap: library
From: ubuntu:20.04
Stage: build

%files
    # Add some_file.txt at the root of the image
    some_file.txt /some_file.txt
```

This works fine when I build with the following command *in the directory which contains the files*:

```
singularity build --fakeroot foobar.sif foobar.def
```

However, it fails if I call the build command from anywhere else (e.g. from a dedicated "build" directory) because it searches `some_file.txt` relative to the current working directory of the build command, not relative to the definition file.

Is there a way to implement the definition file such that the build works independently of where the command is called?  I know that I could use absolute paths but this is not a viable solution in my case.

To make it even more complicated:  My actual definition file is bootstrapping from another local image, which is located in the build directory.  So ideally I would need a solution where some files are found relative the working directory while others are found relative to the location of the definition file.

Comment: I found [this related discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/lbl.gov/forum/#!searchin/singularity/definition$20path$20relative|sort:date/singularity/mRdVInobt20/v5_aSH2EBQAJ) but there is no solution there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Not really

Longer answer: Not really, but there's a reason why and it shouldn't really matter for most use cases. While Docker went the route of letting you specify what your directory context is, Singularity decided to base all of its commands off the current directory where it is being executed. This also follows with `$PWD` being auto-mounted into the container, so it makes sense for it to be consistent.

That said, is there a reason you can't run `singularity build --fakeroot $build_dir/foobar.sif foobar.def` from the repo directory? There isn't any other output written besides the final image and it makes more sense for the directory with the data being used to be the context to work from.

Comment: The reason is that in my actual case, I am bootstrapping from another local image which is located in the build directory (so for this, I actually want it to use the path relative to PWD).  I'll update the question to take this into account.

Comment: Can you just symlink the local image to the repo root? Then you don't have system-specific paths hard coded anywhere and it's all relative to a single directory at execution time

Comment: I guess I have to do something like this.  I'll probably simply abandon the idea of having separate source and build directories for this if it makes the setup too complicated otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, a single, unified directory structure is the way to go. There's no messy intermediate files and keeping everything in the same place helps minimize differences that can impact repeatability of the build process.